# How do I make my bread heavy when baked?

Tags: baking, bread, dough

What ingredient do I add to my bread dough to make it heavy when it's out from the oven?

Comment: Do you mean dense, when you say "heavy"? We generally think of heaviness as the weight of the finished loaf. Other than "heavy" can you explain what goals you are looking for in your bread? What kind of bread are you making? Do you have a recipe for it that we can see?

Comment: I mean the weight of my finished loaf because it's always light.how do I make it heavy

Comment: Why do you want it to be heavy, though... What kind of bread is it? If you're making ciabatta, for example, the entire point is to incorporate air so that you have big holes in the loaf. Can you please give us more information?

Comment: I make whole meal bread for sale because my customers always complain my bread don't have weight

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Chika! If you have a moment, please view the [tour] and the [help]. You may also find [meta] useful for learning about the site. Have fun!

Comment: This question would benefit if you could [edit] it to include the recipe and method that you are using right now. And while you are at it, take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works. Please note that all of our contributors are *volunteers* that write their posts in their free time - complaining (even indirectly) that it may take a while to get an answer is going to rub the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

This is personal experience, and I am not a professional cook. However are you sure you are using the right kind of flour?

I personally find making bread using anything except strong flour makes bread that is light and almost cake like, not very pleasant in my opinion.

Strong flour has more protein and gluten and gives an overall heavier feel to the bread, both in weight and texture/taste.

If you are already using strong flour consider using less yeast, this will cause the bread to rise less and be heavier, but this may make the taste and texture less pleasant.

(A Friend informed me strong flour may have different names depending on your region and part of the world, so if you are not sure exactly how to get it I would suggest researching online to find a good supplier in your area.)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Seasoned Advice. What area of the world are you from (and which knows this as "strong flour")?

Comment: @DanielGriscom "strong flour" is a standard term in British English for high gluten flour.

Comment: In the US I think its "Bread flour" rather than "All Purpose Flour"